# On the simple eigenvalues of edge-transitive graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Are there any examples of edge-transitive connected graphs that have zero as a simple eigenvalue with number of vertices greater than 3?

Eigenvalue means eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix. It is known that a simple eigenvalue of vertex and edge transitive graph $G$ must be equal to $d$ or $-d$, where $d$ is the degree of $G$. For a merely edge transitive graph, due to lack of regularity, we should consider the normalized adjacency matrix instead of the adjacency matrix. I could prove that the simple eigenvalue except for $0$ must be $1$ or $-1$.  I would like to remove the exception.

For example, any complete bipartite graph $K_{n,m}$, $n+m\geq 4$, has $0$ as an eigenvalue of multiplicity $n+m-2\geq 2$.

Comment: Hi ! This seems like an interesting question. Could you provide [context and motivation](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), so that your post meets the [quality guidelines](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) ?

Comment: @SolubleFish
Thank you for your comment. I edited my question and added context and motivation.